# /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../jabcode/lib/libtiff.a when searching for -ltiff

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-make

```
rishabh@rishabh-virtual-machine:~/Downloads/jabcode-master/src/jabcodeWriter$ make
gcc jabwriter.o -L../jabcode/build -ljabcode -L../jabcode/lib -ltiff -lpng16 -lz -lm -O2 -std=c11 -o bin/jabcodeWriter
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../jabcode/lib/libtiff.a when searching for -ltiff
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltiff
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../jabcode/lib/libpng16.a when searching for -lpng16
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng16
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../jabcode/lib/libz.a when searching for -lz
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/jabcodeWriter] Error 1
```

I am building this https://github.com/jabcode/jabcode
but facing problem with it
jabcode folder building was completed but other two folder giving me problem.

trying to get the build done so i can run this program

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to install headers and development libraries for libtiff, libpng16, and libz on the system where you are performing the build.  Apparently, the source distribution you obtained contains pre-built static libraries for these, but they cannot be used because they are not matched to your build environment.  (And this is one reason why such bundling is rather unusual.)